# Delphi: ButtonedEdit + Frame = Bug

Tags: delphi, frame, tbuttonededit

**Delphi XE.**

There is a Buttoned Edit (with the left button), an image list with a picture for the button. All is on a **frame** (it is Ok if on a form).

There is no an indent of the button in a design time, but it is in a run time.

Is it a bug?

[image]
[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes it's a bug. For some reason the `Ctl3D` property of the `TButtonEdit` is not being streamed correctly from the .dfm file when the edit resides in a frame. The streaming is resulting in `Ctl3D` being `False` instead of `True`.

Then, in `TEditButton.UpdateBounds` the following code executes:

```
if (not FEditControl.Ctl3D) and (FEditControl.BorderStyle <> bsNone) then
begin
  FGlyph.Top := 2;
  Inc(NewLeft, 2);
end;
```

This is what is shifting the position of your button 2 pixels right and down.

You can work around the bug by manually setting Ctl3D in code and forcing `UpdateBounds` to be called again.  I did this with an interposer:

```
type
  TButtonedEdit = class(ExtCtrls.TButtonedEdit)
  protected
    procedure Loaded; override;
  end;

procedure TButtonedEdit.Loaded;
begin
  inherited;
  Ctl3D := True;
  LeftButton.Visible := not LeftButton.Visible;
  LeftButton.Visible := not LeftButton.Visible;
  RightButton.Visible := not RightButton.Visible;
  RightButton.Visible := not RightButton.Visible;
end;
```

You can include this in your frame, but make sure that the declaration of the interposed `TButtonedEdit` is before your frame is declared.  Or if the bug afflicts many frames, declare it in a common unit and use that unit in your frame **after** you use `ExtCtrls`.

Now, as for the obvious question as to why the streaming doesn't set `Ctl3D` correctly, I have no answer for that. Perhaps someone more knowledgeable than I am about form streaming could enlighten us!

Comment: Good catch. Now please QC this (I honestly mean it).

Comment: @Rudy I simply haven't got time at the moment since I am on leave from today. When I get back from my hols I'll do it.

Comment: OK, good enough. Or do you want me to report it, mentioning you?

Comment: @Rudy If you felt like reporting it that would be great thanks. I'm just right out of time. You know what it's like when you are getting everything straightened out before holidays!

Comment: yes I know. Although my holidays were in June (I can choose when <g>).

Comment: @rudy It was Sibuyan island and I guess around 10 years ago.